# InstallShield Limited Edition Error ISEXP : error : -5002: Product Configuration 'Express' is not found in the specified project.

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-le

i have developed a application on VisualStudio 2012 and tried InstallShield Limited Edition to build and package the installer. but when i try to build my application i got an error regarding to the InstallShield the error.

ISEXP : error : -5002: Product Configuration 'Express' is not found in the specified project. Verify that the Product Configuration name is correct.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem when I changed from compiling with the "Debug" configuration to compiling with the "Release" configuration. I opened the underlying project setup file (MySetupProject.isproj) and altered the line

```
<Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
```

to read

```
<Configuration>Release</Configuration>
```

and the problem resolved. There may be a way to do the same within the InstallShield UI, but I haven't found it as yet.

Hope this helps.

DavidJE

Answer (score 0):

I changed the solution configuration to point to release and the problem solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when trying to build with a command-line parameter in the project properties. When I removed it it built OK.